# Recommendations to learn Refactoring

Tags: architecture, refactoring, software-design, clean-architecture, maintainability

I have learned **clean code** and some people advise me to learn refactoring. So what are the best resources to learn refactoring and code smells in practical way? I tried to learn from Martin Fowler book **Refactoring improving the design of legacy code** **2nd edition** but in code smells chapter he doesn't explain the smells in code like uncle bob in **clean code**.

Note I have some experience in **TDD** and **clean architecture**.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The resource I've used the most is [Refactoring Guru](https://refactoring.guru/refactoring), it contains a list of code smells and refactoring techniques and how/when to apply them.